# Maximal possible number of induced copies of a subgraph in a graph on $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $H$ with $|V(H)|=d$ vertices and a chromatic number $\mathcal{X}(H)=r$, can I tell what is the maximal number of induced copies of $H$ in a graph on $n$ vertices?

For example, if $H=K_d$, i.e. a clique of size $d$, I know that the maximal number of induced copies of $H$ on $n$ vertices is ${n \choose d}$ (achieved by the complete graph on $n$ vertices).
Is there a result of the more general case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is *inducibility*. This is an area of research with many open problems.

The seminal paper on this topic is [Nicholas Pippenger and Martin Charles Golumbic, The inducibility of graphs, *J. Combin. Theory Ser. B* 19 (1975), 189–203](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895675900842).

For more recent work, see [Chaim Even– Zohar and Nati Linial, A note on the inducibility of $4$-vertex graphs, *Graphs and Combinatorics* 31 (2015), 1367–1380](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-014-1475-4) and references therein.